# How to dynamically inject keys in a php array using values of another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with some values

```
$folderTree = array('files','js','plugins');
```

And another empty array `$scanContainer = array();`.

I would like to map every value from `$folderTree` recursively as a key with an array value in `$scanContainer` and finally obtain an array like this:

```
Array (
    [files] => Array (
            [js] => Array (
                 [plugins] => Array (
                           [0] => plugin1.js,
                           [1] => plugin2.js,
                           ...
                         )
               )
          )
)
```

and in the last array I want to put some values.

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment below and realized that you're actually trying to build an array from a directory tree. This would be another solution to do it.

```
// this is your path; you may build it from an array using implode()
$input = 'files/js/plugins';

$tree  = [];
$pointer = &$tree;
$path = explode('/', $input);

foreach($path as $folder){
    if(!isset($pointer[$folder])){
        $pointer[$folder] = null;
        $pointer = &$pointer[$folder];
    }

    // let's simulate that there are two files within folder 'plugins'
    // in the final application scan each folder for files 
    if($folder == 'plugins'){
        $pointer[0] = "plugin1.js";
        $pointer[1] = "plugin2.js";
    }
}
$pointer = &$tree;

print_r($tree);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [files] => Array (
            [js] => Array (
                    [plugins] => Array (
                            [0] => plugin1.js
                            [1] => plugin2.js
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

[Working demo](http://ideone.com/q8mefD)

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
$values = ['plugin1.js', ...];
$result = array_reduce(
    array_reverse($folderTree),
    function (array $value, $folder) { return [$folder => $value]; },
    $values
);
```

You simply wrap each inner item successively into an outer array, starting with `$values`.

<sub>Note: shortened PHP 5.4+ array notation</sub>

Comment: I do not want to reduce an array values to a single value. To be more explicit, imagine that you have a string like a path `files/js/plugins` and you are in a `loop` of the `plugins` folder. What I would like to do, is to create an array that will have values like a tree. In this case I should have an array with the key `files` that contains another array with the key `js` that finally contains another array with the key `plugins`. The last one should have inside all the filenames from `plugins` folder.

Comment: I know, I get it. Let's put it this way: [**it works.**](http://3v4l.org/rb7Zi) And you *are* reducing an array to a single value. You're reducing the `$folderTree` array with multiple values to a single value (which happens to be an array itself).

Comment: indeed, it works :) sow it after 7 years :D